# Keep container on top after dragging

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, z-index, game-physics

I am migrating game from windows phone to flutter card game. I cannot find the way how to keep the card on the top after dragging.

Stack order is too complex and problematic for such simple action and would involve 4 player active, not active cards, cards on the table, combination sets re-arrangement :( In Windows phone there was a Rectangle with ZIndex which i could set to any rectangle on the screen.

I am missing something similar in flutter. I cannot believe that stack order is only way to solve this because it would make any game development impossible.

I am not using any game engine (maybe thats a problem) but i feel like i do not need it because it is not game-loop based game it is event based - click, drag etc.
Do you know any solution how i can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options -

### 1. [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Update the position of its children by mutating the List and calling `setState` or use [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html).

### 2. [`Material`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html)

The `Material` widget has a property named [`elevation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/elevation.html). Set it's value dynamically to achieve the effect

Comment: Material elevation in stack is not respected i have tested with this:
Material(
                    elevation: 10,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                    )),
                Material(
                    elevation: 0,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 30,
                    ))
Blue comes on top :(
but this would be awesome solution...

Comment: Hey @VytautasPranskunas, as I have mentioned, Stack is one option and Material is another. So you could apply Material elevations anywhere (Expect Stack and Indexed Stack)

Comment: maybe you have some chat so we can talk a bit? because if i am not using stack then i cannot use Positioned and dragging.